# Ajax returns undefined on strings - Form Autofill

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a form that I want to autofill depending on the value on the database.

So when the user enters their email address in the form, it automatically pulls out the telephone and name of that person.

It seems to work when I input a number as the email. However it returns undefined when I type in the email as text.

Here is my code

```
 <script>
var ajax = getHTTPObject();

function getHTTPObject()
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
      // code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } else {
      //alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP!");
    }
    return xmlhttp;
}

function updateCityState()
{
    if (ajax)
    {
        var email = document.getElementById("guest_email").value;

        if(email)
        {

          var url = "test04.php";
            var param = "?guest_email=" + email;


            ajax.open("GET", url + param, true);
            ajax.onreadystatechange = handleAjax;
            ajax.send(null);

        }
    }
}
function handleAjax()                                                                                                                           
{
    if (ajax.readyState == 4)
    {
        citystatearr = ajax.responseText.split(",");

        var gname = document.getElementById('guest_name');
        var gtel = document.getElementById('guest_tel');

        gname.value = citystatearr[0];
        gtel.value = citystatearr[1];
    }
}
</script>
```

**EDIT**

```
<tr>
    <td>Email:</label></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='guest_email' id="guest_email" onChange="updateCityState()"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Name:</td>
    <td><input type='text' id='guest_name' /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Tel:</td>
    <td><input type='text' id='guest_tel'></td>
</tr>
```

test.04.php

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("","","","");

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT guest_name, guest_tel FROM guest WHERE guest_email=".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['guest_email']))  or die(mysqli_error());

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['guest_name'].",".$row['guest_tel'];

?>
```

Comment: There are any errors?

Comment: They are `input` elements? `var gname = document.getElementById('guest_name'); var gtel = document.getElementById('guest_tel');`

Comment: yes, they are from the form.  I have added the form below.

Comment: first of all why are you sending response as comma separated string?

Comment: add your form, pleas )))

Comment: you can have a check before assigning the value to the input...

`gname.value = (!!citystatearr[0]) ? citystatearr[0] : '';
gtel.value = (!!citystatearr[1]) ? citystatearr[1] : '';`

Comment: It does work when I put the email as numbers only like "444444444". Only when the email is a string, it returns undefined

Comment: Check or post your api what is written. Nothing to do here.. its the api that is responding.

Comment: in `html input text` any data is a string.

Comment: @SuyashJadhav, there is no API, that's the code!

Comment: What? you sending AJAX request to `test04.php`, add the code that on this file.

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov done!, that only contains the sql connection + query

Comment: @Nina that's the wrong practice sending data as comma separate. send the response as json object... and that too if query returns result.. 

and on your code too do have a check before assigning value to input as mentioned before

Comment: Hmm. Maybe you should comment everything in `test.04.php` and add `echo trim($_GET['guest_email']) . ', Test'`. (for testing)

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov , it does work when I do that

Comment: Maybe it's because your sql query returns more than one row. check that too, just to be sure.

Comment: Please shared your PHP server code side. I beelive that the problem is with the code PHP

Comment: A tip.. When you use ajax with method GET the function send without paramteres > ajax.send()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this will help ....  Sending data in JSON format(Changed your comma separated response to JSON) ...
this is just for testing... 
*you will also need to change it in your JS code...*
**THIS IS JUST CODE IMPROVEMENT**

```
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['guest_email']);
$query = "SELECT guest_name, guest_tel FROM guest WHERE 
guest_email='".$email."' LIMIT 1";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysql_error());
$response = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $response['guest_name'] = ($row['guest_name'] != '') ? $row['guest_name'] : '';
        $response['guest_tel'] = ($row['guest_tel'] != '') ? $row['guest_tel'] : '';
    }
}
echo  json_encode($response, true);
```

**JS CODE**

```
function handleAjax()                                                                                                                           
{
  if (ajax.readyState == 4)
   {
    var gname = document.getElementById('guest_name');
    var gtel = document.getElementById('guest_tel');
    if(!!ajax.responseText) {
      var result = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
      if(!!result){
        gname.value = (!!result.guest_name) ? result.guest_name : '';
        gtel.value = (!!result.guest_tel) ? result.guest_tel : '';
      } 
    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thank Suyash, it's still doesn't work. I  am getting " unexpected 'guest_name' (T_STRING) in <b>/test04.php</b> on line <b>12</b><br />"

Comment: @Nina their were some mistake updating  the answer. upvote if its working.

Comment: Thanks Suyash, It works now! Just one thing, the values are displayed as {"guest_name":"John Smith" in the input field. How can I display just the name John Smith

Comment: Thanks Suyash! You made my day!

Comment: @nina please upvote or mark this answer as useful if it worked